# Does GdkRectangle have an activate event?

Tags: graphics, gtk, gdk

I want to make a `GdkRectangle` clickable so that I can select it and get a dot in every corner of the rectangle, implying that the user can move or resize the rectangle.

Is there an event that triggers when a `GdkRectangle` is clicked? What's the syntax of the accompanying `g_signal_connect` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GdkRectangle isn't meant to be used like that. It isn't a widget, but just a way to refer to a rectangular area of pixels. You should probably use something like [GtkLayout](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkLayout.html) but without knowing exactly what you're doing, I can't say for sure.